# Windows 7 Desktop Gadget with TODO List Items which include notes?

Tags: windows-7, to-do, desktop-gadget

I'm looking for a TODO list gadget for Windows 7 that includes the ability to add notes to the individual TODO List items.

I found [MyTodo List 1.4.1](http://todo.dj50.ro/) but it doesn't really have this ability.

Alarms would be nice too, but at this point I would settle for just the ability to add notes to TODO List Items.

Comment: Evernote? RememberTheMilk? Google Tasks+Calendar?

Comment: You might get a better response at http://productivity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would someone please be so kind as to migrate this to http://productivity.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Rainlendar Lite - has all the functions you want!

There is also a calendar, events, and so forth, but you can customize the skins to remove the options you don't want.  You can also resize the width of the to do list, if the default is too narrow or too wide.